# XSD - Max Children?

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, xsd

Trying to work this out, any help would be appreciated.

I have an xml file laid out as follows :

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?> 
<test>
<Name>Folder exists check</Name>
<type>
    <DoesFolderExist>
        Synchronisation Errors
    </DoesFolderExist>
</type>
</test>
```

For the `<type>` section, I would like my xsd to be only able to have ONE child, but the actual type may vary, it may not necessarily be "DoesFolderExist" - it could be "FolderCount", or whatever. Basically, it can only have one child, but that child may be one of any predefined type that my users can choose from. Can I get a simple example here of how I might lay that out in my xsd?

Here is what I currently have, and I am not to sure about where to go from here :

```
       string XSDMarkup = 
        @"xsd:schema xmlns:xsd='http://www.ws.org/2001/XMLSchema'>
            <xsd:element name='tests'>
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element name='test' minOccurs='1'/>
                    <xsd:element name='type' minOccurs='1' maxOccurs='1'>
                        <xsd:sequence>
                            <xsd:element
        ";
```

I know the xsd above is incomplete and will not work, but I am obviously not finished yet.

Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You want a choice, not a sequence, for the type of the `type` element.

Your schema document has other problems, though:  in particular, the type of an element must be given using either a `type` attribute or a type definition appearing as a child of the element declaration.  So your declaration for `tests` (for example) should take the form

```
<xsd:element name='tests'>
  <xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element name="test"> ... </xsd:element>
      <xsd:element name="type"> ... </xsd:element>
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
```

It may be worth your while to spend half an hour with a good XSD tutorial.